# QLineEdit not able to Undo after calling SetText() in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

In my application I am having many `QLineEdit` widgets. The user can edit them.
I have observed that if I add text to a `QLineEdit` through `GUI` & then if that `QLineEdit` has the cursor then if I press `ctrl+z` then it undoes the text so that there is no text in it.
Now if I set the text by code by `SetText("some text")`, then `undo` does not work by `ctrl+z` method. Even if I `undo` by code still it does not clear the text. What is the problem? Am I missing something?
Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`undo` probably thinks that the value you set by `SetText` should be treated as default start value, that doesn't need `undo`ing. Normal behavior as it seems for me.

Here is `SetText()` definition:

This property holds the line edit's text.
Setting this property clears the selection, clears the undo/redo history, moves the cursor to the end of the line and resets the modified property to false. The text is not validated when inserted with setText(). 
The text is truncated to maxLength() length.
By default, this property contains an empty string.
Calling setText() resets the modified flag to false.

Perhaps if you set `setModified ( bool )` to true, will fix this for you

Edit:
Found workaround : `insert(QString text)` works with `undo()` just fine

Comment: but I want to have the ability to undo so that QLineEdit behaves as if the text was added through GUI!

Comment: ok thanks I will try that & get back to you. But since it clears the undo/redo memory, will calling undo, clear the text?